# HTML 5- adding a navigation bar to a page

Tags: html, navbar

I'm just having a go at creating a website for a friend, but I've not actually done any development for a few months, and so I'm a bit rusty at the moment.

I've started putting a basic page together, to use as a template for all of the pages of the website, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting the horizontal navigation bar to display on the page beneath the logo, and I was just wondering if anyone could explain to me why it's not showing?

The HTML that I have for this is: (code updated 25/09/2013 @ 17:40)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cosy Hearts- Home</title>
<style type = "text/css">
#navbar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
#navbar ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src = "images\masterPageTop.jpg" width = "700" height = "800" alt = "Cosy Hearts Banner" />

<ul>
    <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a> | </li>
    <li><a href = "products.html">Products</a> | </li>
    <li><a href = "aboutUs.html">About Us</a> | </li>
    <li><a href = "contactUs.html">Contact Us</a> | </li>
    <li><a href = "termsAndConditions.html">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
</ul>



</body>



</html>
```

Currently, when viewing the page in the browser, the logo image is displayed at the top of the page as intended, but then the navigation bar, which I've tried to created using a div and horizontal list is not displayed at all...

I was just wondering if anyone could explain to me why this is, and what I need to do to get it to display?

Cheers!

**Edit 25/09/2013**

I've edited the code to show changes made as suggested, also here's the screenshot of the page when viewed in Chrome (it displays exactly the same in Firefox):

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the image is displayed (although not longer central, having removed the 'center' tags as suggested- will sort this out later with CSS. But, the navigation bar is not displayed on the page at all, and I can't tell why this is... does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: An image in the HEAD (and CENTER) is invalid for starters.

Comment: The `<head>` tag is not for page content. It's for the base page title (the `<title>` tag, which is displayed in the tab/window your page is in), and for putting in various other data like `<meta>`s, `<link>`s, `<script>`s, and `<style>`s. Page content should be contained within the `<body>` tag. So move your `<img>` and `<p>` tags there. Also, `<center>` is a deprecated tag, so don't use it. Center the image with CSS styles instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is a little bit botched... you may want to review the purposes of tags like `<head>` and `<body>`. The following HTML will give you the desired effect.

### [See this working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/PthjR/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cosy Hearts- Home</title>
    <style type = "text/css">
        #navbar ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        #navbar ul li {
            list-style-type: none;
            display:inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <img src="images\masterPageTop.jpg" width="700" height="800" alt="Cosy Hearts Banner" />
    </center>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> | </li>
            <li><a href="products.html">Products</a> | </li>
            <li><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a> | </li>
            <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a> | </li>
            <li><a href="termsAndConditions.html">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to indent things in such a way that you can easily remember what the layout of an HTML document looks like. As your page gets more complex, you might consider putting your CSS in a separate file -- say, `stylesheet.css` -- and including it by adding the following to the `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for your answer. I've tried making the changes you suggested, but I'm still having the same problem when viewing the page in my browser... any ideas why?

Comment: Is there any other code that might be interfering? Which browser are you using, and can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: There isn't any other code that might be interfering- so far I only have the code for the one page, which is all in my question. I've tried using Chrome and Firefox, but have the same problem in both- screenshot provided.

Comment: In your edit, you appear to have removed the `<div id='#navbar'>`, so those `#navbar ul` and `#navbar ul li` selectors in your stylesheet won't apply to the menu anymore. You should get rid of the `ul { ... }` statement you have on the bottom, and then remove `#navbar` from those first two selectors so that they just read `ul` and `ul li`, respectively. Beyond that, I copied and pasted your code into a new HTML document and opened it in Chrome, and everything appeared as it was styled. There must be something else interfering with your content from somewhere.